What to do when your PhD advisor offers the suggestion to change labs? Could I change PhD programs?
I am a first year PhD student in the US. Up until now, I knew that the work I was producing/presenting was subpar/only the minimum. My advisor has repeatedly told me that PhD students become experts in one field and that requires more than superficial knowledge. Consequently, he expects me to have more solid understanding of basic knowledge in my field- which is reasonable.
Today apparently was the straw that broke the camel's back. He asked me about how I did my data analysis but I could not explain it well, saying that I found a package that computed it. Afterwards I looked into it and explained it to him.
He then told me nicely that to him, it appears that I do not have an interest in the work that our lab does. Research should incite your curiosity, prompt you to look into things you don't know, and find out more about it. This process should be natural. And, above all, it shouldn't make you unhappy.
He concluded that I should look into other research areas that I would actually find interesting.
I am not sure what to do. I have been unhappy due to my lack of progress; it's incredibly frustrating because my advisor had high hopes for me and I was really looking forward to doing research with him at the start.
What should I do? I don't want to quit after I recently made up my mind to put in more effort and actually feel better/enjoy my research more. At the same time, I'm not sure if I want to work with my professor who demonstrates a lack of confidence/large investment in me now.
If I do need to change labs, I'd like to change my program altogether. I don't want to remain at my current department. How could I change programs?

Well, so far you do not seem to have given your professor a reason to have confidence in you. And, if you continue to act the way you are, it is unlikely that some other professor would have confidence. So, you need to change what you are doing. Whether starting to perform well would regain trust with your current professor is the real question, or if you would have to change groups and perform well there is needed.

I realize that this probably isn't the answer you want, but I think your advisor is trying to kindly steer you in a more appropriate direction. Since you asked for advice explicitly, I would suggest you look into other labs/programs at your university and see which ones appeal to you the most.
To be a bit blunt: while one anecdote doesn't represent a whole year, saying your data analysis is done by a package that you don't understand is not just an "oops", it's toeing the line to scientific misconduct by way of negligence. If you continue in this lab, you'll need to invest a lot more time and energy into understanding your methods- and it's absolutely valid to realize that this isn't for you and you'd prefer something else.
While it's great to be motivated for a topic in general, your PhD is composed of years of day to day research work, which can be very different from the big picture (e.g. pipetting vs "curing cancer"). For example, research in my field involves writing a lot of code, and while that's not directly related to the science, someone who hates programming would be absolutely miserable.

Research should incite your curiosity, prompt you to look into things you don't know, and find out more about it. This process should be natural. And, above all, it shouldn't make you unhappy.

I think that this is beautifully put. It should be fun and exciting to get a chance to review and solidify your grasp on the field. In mine, it's extremely common for PhD students to get a bit overexcited and go down a few rabbit holes when reading up on new methods. You say that you've made up your mind to put in more effort and to "actually feel better". I'm not sure that you can just decide to be passionate about a topic, and I don't think doubling down with more effort on things that don't seem to be working is the right move.
You're not a failure, or somehow a worse scientist or person, for deciding that you don't like a specific topic (or subfield) as much as you originally thought. Change may seem scary, but since you are only a year in, I think your professor is right to suggest that you go for it and try to find a project that truly makes you feel as described in the quote. While it may seem safer, 4+ more years of "resolving to be happier" sounds like a very long slog.

I would take your advisor's words at face value. He might have your best interests at heart and be trying to free you from any sense of obligation to stay in his lab. I would not think of this as "the straw that broke the camel's back" nor take his advice as an attack on your talent or work ethic.
Reading threads here on academia.SE, I've come to realize I was very fortunate to have a wise and kind PhD advisor who put real effort into developing me as a person and as a mathematician. Nevertheless, we once had a conversation much like the one you are describing. I'd been splitting my time between my master's in computer science and my PhD work with him. Since pure math requires a lot of learning before you can even start doing research, we were still in the "reading course" phase. But in computer science I was already proving results that would go into my thesis. I used to mention them to my PhD advisor, often along with an apology for why I had not made more progress in our reading course. He once suggested that I might be happier (and have a happier career) as a computer scientist, and I felt mortified, like he was rejecting me. But now, looking back on that moment, I realize he was just giving me an option, as well as some spot-on advice about the relative difficulty of securing an academic position in math vs CS. As an advisor, I think back on that moment a lot, and try to remind myself how much students can look up to their advisors, and how easy it is to accidentally hurt their feelings if they misinterpret what I meant. Anyway, after that conversation, I did buckle down a bit and make more progress on the math side, and my advisor never again suggested we stop working together. I don't think he meant to do this, but it does seem conversations like this sometimes light a fire under a student (in a good way).
Ok, so to your specific questions.

What should I do? I don't want to quit after I recently made up my mind to put in more effort and actually feel better/enjoy my research more. At the same time, I'm not sure if I want to work with my professor who demonstrates a lack of confidence/large investment in me now.

Hopefully my story convinced you that the "lack of confidence" thing might not be fully accurate. Advisors know that each student is a work in progress. You can respond "I thought about our conversation, and realized that I really DO find this research interesting, especially X,Y,Z. It's finally starting to 'click' and that makes me very happy. I think it's premature to switch labs just yet. Is it ok with you if we proceed with the research and come back to this conversation in a few months?"

I have been unhappy due to my lack of progress; it's incredibly frustrating because my advisor had high hopes for me and I was really looking forward to doing research with him at the start.

Those feelings are super common in grad school. You can find a zillion posts here expressing the same feelings and getting advice from professors about how it gets better.

If I do need to change labs, I'd like to change my program altogether. I don't want to remain at my current department. How could I change programs?

You can apply for other programs as a transfer student, and there are lots of threads about that here on Academia. The consensus seems that you usually take a step down or a lateral move in terms of quality of institution. Plus, your advisor's letter would probably matter. Therefore, since you said you'd rather stay, I advise you to stay and show your advisor that you are in fact making progress and are not disinterested.
